# CNN Model is predicting only 1 class

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have coded a CNN model for binary classification. My dataset is biased(class 1 of 56000 images and class 2 of 3000 images).
I am testing on 108 images(54 of each class). My model is prediction every images as class 1. Can you tell me what's wrong with my model and how can I improve it?

```
IMG_SIZE = 32
LR = 1e-1


convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3], name='input')

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='/home/anas/Argentinadata/log')






train = training_data[:50000]
test =training_data[50000:]




X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)

test_y = [i[1] for i in test]



print(len(test_x))


print(len(X))

print(len(Y))


model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=25, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}),
            snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

That just means that the model found it easiest to just predict one class and get an accuracy of ~95%.
Try training with weights or duplicating the images of class 2 until you have ~50/50 split of class 1 and class 2.

Comment: Yeah I tried inserting images manually to make images of each class equal, but now my model is predicting all images as class 2.

Comment: How about increasing the amount of epochs? Maybe 25 is not enough for the model to train correctly.

It might also help to preprocess your data some more, by subtracting the average pixel value for example. How is the error rate after each epoch, maybe that might help to find a solution

Comment: increasing epochs mayn't help as when a model predicts a single class its actually a case of overfit.

Answer (score 0):

Two things (more direct ones), I will suggest in this case:

1.use batchsize=30 - 40

2. shuffle your data to include better diversity in each batch

you can use data_utils for this purpose from tflearn:

```
tflearn.data_utils.shuffle (your_array)
```

you can look at the documentation [here](http://tflearn.org/data_utils/#shuffle)

other thing you can do is resample the data to include more minority classes but you don't have a large enough parent sample for that. So you can try to manually insert data of minority classes in batches.

You can also train a generative model on the minority class and generate some data points(progressively) but it may cause overfit for the minority classes

A more complicated fix can be to modify the cost function, by doing that you assign higher cost if there is a wrong prediction for the minority class.

Comment: Yeah I tried doing inserted images manually to make images of each class equal, but now my model is predicting all the images as class 2. Can you suggest some other way?

Comment: please try using a bigger batch size for one
Secondly don't insert all the similar class images all in together into a particular batch, that is kindly shuffle them before they are being used to train.